# Can we use an or statement when using proc sql join

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to join 2 tables using a proc sql. I have one key variable in one table and 2 key variables in an another table. I would like to use an or statement and do something like this

```
proc sql;
    create table merged_SQL as
    select L.*, R.B
    from one as L left join
         two as R
         on L.A= R.A or  L.B= R.A;
    quit;
```

I know its not possible with this code but is there a way to do that making some modifications. P.S. all the variables are the same format.

Comment: Yes.  But the performance will likely be aweful.

Comment: That code would likely work fine....are you getting errors?

Comment: As above comments say, the code will work fine, but will have poor performace if you can show some sample data, someone would help you with good alternatives

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `UNION` clause. The query would look something like:

```sql
select L.*, R.A
from one as L join two as R on L.A = R.A
union
select L.*, R.B
from one as L join two as R on L.B = R.B
```

Depending on your data structures, you might consider `UNION ALL`.